# How to change the highlighting style?

Tags: css

In Google Chrome, an highlighted (= selected, when your cursor is inside) textbox is surrounded by an orangish colored line which is not very distintly visible.

Is there a way to change this using CSS? I want to enhance the highlight even more.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
input:focus {
    outline: 15px solid pink;
}
```

Comment: @SLaks is there a way to get rid of it instead?

Comment: @SLaks that works, but you have to remove the `:active`. Thanks!

Comment: @SLaks, I was talking about the highlight, not the outline.

Comment: @keoki: It should actually be `:focus`, not `:active`; my mistake.

Comment: @Lazer: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @SLaks: I have included a pic in the question.. I am referring to the highlight that kicks in when a text box is selected. Sorry, if I am using the wrong term here..

Comment: @Lazer: That's exactly what my code should change.  (Except that I got the selector wrong)

Comment: focus is what I was looking for, earlier I was just getting a static boundary, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the blur effect on the border here's an example of how to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/aE4PY/

You can prevent the default Chrome behavior by setting `outline:none` on `input` itself which will also apply to any pseudo class (like `:focus`)

```
input {
    border:solid 1px #aaa;
    outline:none;
}
input:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px yellow;
     -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 4px yellow;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px yellow;
        -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 4px yellow;
         -o-box-shadow: 0 0 4px yellow;
            box-shadow: 0 0 4px yellow;
}
```

In order for the `box-shadow` to work I had to manually set the `border`.  Also, the most current versions of browsers support box-shadow without vendor prefixes.

for some bonus effects like rounded corners and transition easing check this post out
http://blog.gesteves.com/post/475773360/css-glow-effects-with-box-shadow